# ios correct way to use constraintLessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingAfter for trailingAnchor

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I'd like to programmatically layout a `UILabel` that should fit the width of the screen, with the system spacing as left and right insets. Here's my code:

```
statusLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.smallSystemFontSize)
statusLabel.numberOfLines = 0
statusLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(statusLabel)

statusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: otherView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
statusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
statusLabel.trailingAnchor.constraintLessThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1),
statusLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: someOtherView.topAnchor, constant: 0)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

the label is laid out using the system spacing as the left inset, as intended, but its `trailingAnchor` seems to be equal to the superview's `trailingAnchor` rather than adding a system spacing between the two.

I've tried using `constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter` and `constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToSystemSpacingAfter` but got the same results.

Any ideas on how to get the system spacing between the label and its superview's trailing anchors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the order Like this

```
view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(statusLabel.trailingAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
```

view first & statusLabel next.